# jsf primefaces datatable p:columns

Tags: jsf, datatable, primefaces

ive got a Primefaces DataTable like this

```
<p:dataTable
   value="#{valueList.value}"
   var="value"
   selection="#{valueList.selected}"
   id="measurementTable"
   paginator="true"
   rows="20"
   rowsPerPageTemplate="20,25,30,35,40"/>
```

and dynamic Columns with this

```
<p:columns
  value="#{valueList.columns}"
  var="column"
  columnIndexVar="colIndex"
 />
```

this works fine and my Datatable looks good , but when i add

```
  sortBy="#{value.charge}"
```

to `p:columns` and i was click on column to sort the css style is destroyd and ive got a List with my Data not a DataTable, this is very ugly.

---

My code

```
<p:dataTable
        value="#{measurementList.measurements}"
        var="measurement"
        selection="#{measurementList.selected}"
        id="measurementTable"
        paginator="true"
        rows="20"
        rowsPerPageTemplate="20,25,30,35,40"
        rowKey="#{measurement.mdkFid}"
        emptyMessage="#{measurementList.getCapString('no_records_found')}">

        <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:18px" />

        <p:column>
            <p:commandLink title="#{measurementList.getString('edit')}" update=":contentPanel">
                <h:outputText styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-pencil" />
                <f:actionListener binding="#{measurementList.editSelected(measurement) }" />
                <f:actionListener binding="#{navigation.goTo('/xhtml/measurements/editMeasurement.xhtml') }" />
            </p:commandLink>
        </p:column>

        <p:columns
            value="#{measurementList.columns}"
            var="column"
            columnIndexVar="colIndex"
            styleClass="measurementListDatatableColumn"
            sortBy="#{column.displayName}" 
            >
            <f:facet name="header">#{column.displayName}</f:facet>
                <p:column>
                    #{measurement[column.methodName]}
                </p:column>
        </p:columns>
```

Comment: A bit OT: Why are you loading a message for `emptyMessage` from your backing bean's method? You can directly use `#{msg[SOME_MESSAGE_KEY]}` and put a `<f:loadBundle var="msg" basename="org.example.localization.project" />` in your "master" template. Then create `project_XX.bundle` in the said package (source code) and it should be loaded.

Answer (score 4):

Your sort should look something like

```
sortBy="#{value[column.charge]}"
```

Take a look at the showcase example [DataTable - Dynamic Columns](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableDynamicColumns.jsf)

Change

```
 <p:columns
        value="#{measurementList.columns}"
        var="column"
        columnIndexVar="colIndex"
        styleClass="measurementListDatatableColumn"
        sortBy="#{column.displayName}" 
        >
        <f:facet name="header">#{column.displayName}</f:facet>
            <p:column>
                #{measurement[column.methodName]}
            </p:column>
    </p:columns>
```

into

```
 <p:columns
        value="#{measurementList.columns}"
        var="column"
        columnIndexVar="colIndex"
        styleClass="measurementListDatatableColumn"
        sortBy="#{measurement[column.methodName]}" 
        >
        <f:facet name="header">
            #{column.displayName}
        </f:facet>

         #{measurement[column.methodName]}

    </p:columns>
```

---

In general : the same EL expression that is used to display the data of the column , should be used for the `sortBy`

Comment: do you have `charge` property  + getter in your  `column` object ?

Comment: yes ive got setter an getter but the value charge holds an methodname for the value object

Comment: show your value that is used for display inside your `p:columns` , like ` #{car[column.property]}  ` in the showcase...

Comment: when i use the example from the showcase this will show me the same sh*t

Comment: in showcase they use `<f:facet name="header">  
                #{column.header}  
            </f:facet>  
  
            #{car[column.property]}` , show your code...

Comment: With #{measurement[column.methodName]} its the Field in my BackingBean Measurement , example #{measurement.id} an this returns my value

Comment: why do you have `<p:column>` inside the `<p:columns>` ?

Comment: did you mean the first two columns ?

Comment: `<p:columns
            value="#{measurementList.columns}"
            var="column"
            columnIndexVar="colIndex"
            styleClass="measurementListDatatableColumn"
            sortBy="#{column.displayName}" 
            >
            <f:facet name="header">#{column.displayName}</f:facet>
                <p:column>
                    #{measurement[column.methodName]}
                </p:column>
        </p:columns><p:columns>`  why do you have <p:column> inside the

Comment: In general : the same EL expression that is used to display the data of the column , should be used for the `sortBy`